# Does anybody know if it's possible to make nested quicklists, or if that feature has been at least considered?

Tags: launcher, quicklists

For example, I have a Launcher icon called Google Tools. When I right click it, it gives options to open Google Docs, Gmail, Calendar, etc. However I want to know if there's any way to make the Google Docs portion extend further and show New Document, New Spreadsheet, etc. Is this possible, or maybe planned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, but even if it is already planned, it would be still good to voice your idea on the Ayatana mailing list.

Comment: +1 on voicing this on the ayatana mailing list. Having somethings like - (close extra options) and + (show extra options) would be cool and very handy.