# Is it possible to create nested Quicklists?

Tags: unity, quicklists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anybody know if it's possible to make nested quicklists, or if that feature has been at least considered?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40883/does-anybody-know-if-its-possible-to-make-nested-quicklists-or-if-that-feature)

Is it possible to create nested quicklists for the Unity launcher - possibly - is this a future planned capability?